# Equivalent statement without using a conditional

Tags: real-analysis

How can you write an equivalent mathematical statement of this, without using a conditional? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the conditional (the arrow $\Rightarrow$) the following way: for any two propositions (or formulae), the symbol $P\Rightarrow Q$ means, in plain language, 'if $P$ is true, then $Q$ is also true'. Note that it says nothing about $Q$ whenever $P$ is false.

So, $P\Rightarrow Q$ holds as long as we do not have $P \wedge \neg Q$; $P\Rightarrow Q$ is equivalent to $\neg(P\wedge \neg Q)$, or, put other way via De Morgan, to $\neg P\vee Q$.

So your statement would become

$$\forall x,y\in \mathbb R\quad y\geq x\vee \, \exists z\in\mathbb R\, x<z<y.
$$

Comment: ohhh, that makes sense! thank you for the detailed explanation

Comment: You're welcome!